# Home Networking - extending connection to new wires

Tags: networking, router, lan, home-networking, modem

I hope this is the appropriate place to ask this. I currently have internet going to a single network jack inside my house (downstairs), with a provider router connected to it.

I'd like to connect another existing cable (going upstairs) to the network. The downstairs cable is connected straight into the modem pictured below, and I'm wondering if it's possible for the upstairs cable to be plugged in here as well.

The issue I'm facing is IP configuration for devices connected to the modem, and I don't have much networking/telcom knowledge. It's my understanding that if the modem were to have a dhcp server, it would generate the settings for all devices connected to it, but that wasn't the case when I hooked up my laptop.

So do I have the option of connecting more than 1 cable to this modem, or will all my connections have to pass trough the provider router first?

[image]

Comment: *"It's my understanding that if the modem were to have a dhcp server..."* -- And NAT and a firewall. According to the [datasheet](https://www.alliedtelesis.com/sites/default/files/documents/datasheets/img626mod_ds.pdf), there is a DHCP server (and NAT & fw), as well as mention of "Static and dynamic IP address assignment".  *"that wasn't the case when I hooked up my laptop"* -- A negative description of what did not happen is not that helpful for diagnosis.  Maybe if DHCP is properly configured, then you could simply insert the upstairs plug in the LAN #2 socket (and not need another router).

Comment: If that is supposed to be an Ethernet cable plugged into LAN socket #1, then that is one poorly-made cable, e.g. too much untwisting of the wire pairs.

Comment: Rule 1: Don't make your own ethernet cables if that's how they end up. Buy them ready made. The one we can see in the picture will not work for modern gigabit ethernet. Once you have proper cables, that router has room for 5 more before you need another device.

Comment: @sawdust am I correct to assume the DHCP configuration is out of my hands and should be happening on the provider side?

Comment: @tetsujin this is the cable the technician did when they set this up - it's a short wack job of a patch cable that splices directly into the house cable in a junction box right below this box, and I intend to replace it. As my post says, I did hook up my laptop with a proper cable to the other ports but I'm not getting an IP configuration

Comment: Yeah - I found the manufacturer's information on it & it's some kind of outdoor telco box I actually don't fully understand. I'd ask your ISP what they expect you to connect to it.

Comment: @Rubens -- No, you are not correct.  Configuration of a modem/gateway is typically performed from the LAN side.  Remote configuration of level 3 functionality is often disabled for security.  *"... but I'm not getting an IP configuration"* -- You persist in providing only negative descriptions.  Provide descriptions of what actually happens.  What are the private (if any) IP addresses used on the LAN?

Comment: *"I did hook up my laptop with a proper cable to the other ports but I'm not getting an IP configuration"* -- Test the functionality of these other LAN ports by moving the one working connection from LAN #1.

Comment: @sawdust I'm not sure what I should be providing - my understanding of what is relevant and what is not is limited. The router connected to port #1 is set to get a public IP address & DNS automatically from the ISP. It then creates the LAN and distributes private IPs to my connected devices. So in my limited understanding, the modem is currently not doing any routing even though it appears to be capable of it, which is what I'm trying to achieve. In doing more research, it appears that the modem could be set to bridge mode by the IPS - does that sound plausible or am I saying something stupid?

Comment: *"The router connected to port #1 is set to get a public IP address ..."* -- ***That*** is new and salient information.  *"it appears that the modem could be set to bridge mode"* -- Yes, that's plausible, and could explain why the laptop is not *"getting an IP configuration"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So do I have the option of connecting more than 1 cable to this modem,
> or will all my connections have to pass trough the provider router
> first?

You would need to add a Router to the Modem. Bridge it so the router gets internet. Then you can distribute wires from it to sites in your house.

So the answer to your question is, Yes, you need a router (to distribute the signals in the house)

**Followup Note:** You do need a Router to distribute signals. It may be that your modem includes a router (some do). If so, you can also use this to fulfill the router need. I always prefer to add my own router for security, flexibility, and control over my own gear.

Comment: that answers my question, appreciate it.

Comment: You are very welcome and I was happy to help. I use a setup like in my home.

Comment: Why would another router be required. I can see 6 ethernet LAN ports out the back of that one. What it does need is proper cables, not that DIY shambles.